# Selection Formula with Brackets

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a beginner in Crystal Reports and I'm slowly increasing my knowledge.

I am trying to pass a selection criteria to a report and I wanted to know the best way of achieving the following.

1) NAME

2) NAME

3) NAME

4) NAME [AA]

5) NAME [AB]

6) NAME [AC]

7) NAME

In the above example, I only want to see the information contained within a specific column where it is equal to 'NAME' The rows containing brackets [ ] are the ones I would like to exclude.

Please can I get some assistance on how to achieve this?

Only want to see info contained with, 1, 2, 3 & 7.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is your column name? as per your description(please confirm) you want the data which does not have brackets([]) , right? and where you want in selection formula ? pl. confirm.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. the column name is 'USERS'. I would only want to see the name and nothing beyond that. The format for the field is NAME [] and would like to remove any brackets displayed after the name. I would like this as a record selection against the workbook.

Comment: and other querie's answer

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post, what else would do you mean. If I had a column with a NAME [AA] eg. BILL [AA], then I would only want to see BILL and nothing contained there after.....

Comment: What is workbook? what is the meaning of "record selection against the workbook". As I understand that data will come as per above, but while display discard whatever after bracket start? right.

Comment: Don't you appreciate the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

InStr is substring find function of Crystal report. You just copy in your report selection formula (this will only take data which does not have [ and ] charcter):

```
InStr({table.USERS}, '[') = 0 and InStr({table.USERS}, ']') = 0
```

To understand more, check this link You can check null too.

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=2409

[Selection formula excluding rows with columns having null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070288/selection-formula-excluding-rows-with-columns-having-null-values)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205398/Crystal-Report-Filtering-Using-Selection-Parameter

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. Go to `Record Selection Formula` and write

   {DatabaseField}="Name"

2.

```
 if (InStr({DatabaseField}),"]" <> 0)
Then {DatabaseField}={DatabaseField}
```